# communication project using android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, wifi, communication

i'm doin my project in 8th sem telecomm engineering, and i'm plannin to create a DUPLEX(not confident whether it'd be full or half) communication app using bluetooth and wifi as channels,something more advanced than a simple walkie talkie, and i was wondering if this is possible for a one man army??? also i was wondering if it is possible to do so with android versions 2.2 and above... can i just program the bluetooth settings in app in such a way, that, it doesn't pop up for user permission to accept a voice message from the calling party??
and is there a possibility for creating multiple channels(one for Forward Voice Channel and one for Reverse Voice Channel) using bluetooth or wifi?? here's a list of few knowledge i possess:

JAVA:  basics, done some gui in desktops, know some imp classes,only SE6...
WIRELESS COMMUNICATION: learning it this semester, stuff like how base station accepts incoming mobile station request and redirects it to dest, mostly 1g in our portions...
OPERATING SYSTEMS: general, looking forward to learning android and linux os... 
C,C++,DSP,and SOME ELECTRONICS...

oh, and iwoul like to implement these well within 7 months duration...

people please ENLIGTHEN me with your wisdom and references to useful websites ASAP...

my THANKS AND WISHES to thee...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first big problem i see is that on using wifi for this, and as i understood it is some sort of (advanced) walkie-talkie app with no rooter inbetween the communicating phones, you have to implement adhoc-wlan on your android device, which is not supported by android, so you will need a rooted device for that, and the implementation of adhoc-wlan on android is definitve possible (have a look at this code: http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) but nothing easy (i have done it myself for an university project).

And you asked if you can avoid the permission pop-up for an incoming message, but on an android phone activating your bluetooth or pairing it with an other device will always ask for permission from the user.

I cant help about the multiple channels you were asking for.

As Answer to your big Question: "is it possible for a one man army?" i would say generelly yes, but it depends on how much other stuff you have to do. Since you were writing this is an project for university, i dont know if this is your only project and you can invest a lot of time in it. If so i guess it is possible, but it will be an quite big project and you should be willing to work yourself relativly deep into networking stuff.

On google.Code you can find some projects similar (at least the wifi part) to what you think about to do, take a look at them...

Comment: the problem is im learnin netwrkin this sem, know a bit basics abt osi layers,need more time to dwel into that sub,so i was lookin fwd to stickin with the plain ol' bluetooth, is there a way i can establish a full duplex comm channel or, i would regress back to simplex...

Comment: oh, and lets abandon the wifi part here, and think about using 3g(mostly coz its getin cheaper by the day) in establishing a simple local comm network. is it feasible? what are the hardships that i have to face, and what new things should i learn? oh, and im supposed to submit the project, well within 7 months from now... and thanks for the link, bookmarked it..:)

Comment: @MaK well, as i said i dont know about the duplex thing on bluetooth, and i have personally never used 3g for something like this, but the best way for you to find out what passible is to take a look on what generally provided by android, and if a feature is not available you have to implement it yourself... i definitly dont know, but i guess using 3g for such a thing will be quite hard, since i guess it is not supported to use it for something like this... but this is more an educated guess than knowledge